# How to set bits in byte without loop

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I am really confused, but cannot to do simple task as it seems:

I simply need to set number of bits in byte.

For example:

I need 5 bits set. So I need `0xb00011111`.

Is it possible to do this without loop?

Also I'd not like to write lot of `#defines` too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For any integer `n` less than the number of bits in the word, the mask you need is:

```
const unsigned int mask = (1u << n) - 1;
```

No loop required.

A simple function using this:

```
unsigned int set_lsbs(unsigned int n)
{
  return (1u << n) - 1;
}
```

The ten first results are:

```
0: 0x0
1: 0x1
2: 0x3
3: 0x7
4: 0xf
5: 0x1f
6: 0x3f
7: 0x7f
8: 0xff
9: 0x1ff
```

Note: the syntax `0xb00011111` is not not a binary literal, that 'b' is simply interpreted as a hex digit.

Comment: Yes, I wrote `0xb00011111` just  for simplicity. Thank you very much!

Comment: `0xb00011111` is valid C, but it's not like what the OP expected

Comment: Oh, right `0xb00011111` is valid C but a very big hex literal :) The OP intended `0b00011111` which is not valid C, since C does not have binary literals.

Answer (score 3):

Generation of a mask to set the least-significant 5 bits for any integer type can be done thus:

```
mask = ~((~0u) << 5) ;
```

This will create an integer value with the least significant 5 bits set to 1 and all higher-order bits regardless of integer type set to 0.

Specifically for the 8 bit type in question:

```
uint8_t mask = ~((~0u) << 5) ;
```

To explain how this works (ignoring intermediate integer types which are larger than 8 bits):

- `~0u` (one's compliment of zero) = `0x11111111`
- Then shifted by 5 = `0x11100000`
- Finally the one's complement of that = `0x00011111`

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do this without loop?

**yes**, it's possible to `set` `n` bits in given number without loop but not `random` bits, you can set `n` consecutive bits.

To set a single bit at given position

```
   num = num | 1 << pos ;
```

For setting `5` consecutive bits in given no you can use below logic

```
num = num | 31 << pos;
```

Here

```
31 ==> 1x2^0 + 1x2^1 + .. => 31 is the sum of 5 ones(1 1111)
```

Comment: What if I need more bits? More `case`? No, only two bitwise operations make same code, fast and easy.

Comment: `double pow(float, int);` returns double. Did you read answers before yours? This is very bad example and very bad advice. Better delete it.

Comment: I modified my answer